# How to convert to Data time format (Day - Full month - YYYY hh:MM?

Tags: r, date

How to convert to date time format?

```
as.POSIXlt("10-March-2017 11:00", format=   "%d-%B-%Y %h:%m")
```

I'm getting an "NA" for the output. How would you convert this in R?

Comment: Capital H and captial M?

Answer (score 1):

At least with R 3.4.2 on High Sierra:

```
as.POSIXlt("10-March-2017 11:00", format=   "%d-%B-%Y %H:%M")
## [1] "2017-03-10 11:00:00 CST"
```

works just by changing to %H:%M

Answer (score 0):

I found a second solution to this problem.

I got the solution from:
[Easily Converting Strings to Times and Dates in R with flipTime](https://www.r-bloggers.com/easily-converting-strings-to-times-and-dates-in-r-with-fliptime/)
January 31, 2018
By Mathew McLean

```
AsDateTime("10-March-2017 11:00")
```

**Note**: I had to remove NA from the column for this to work.